# How to test a Login page which have other tests?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium web-driver. I am writing test to test a login page. My issue is- I have 2 tests, one for valid login and one for invalid login. Ideally, they should be independent but in my case they one case opens the page after login so another test fails.

I have tried relaunching the browser for every test but I don't think that's ideal.

Login Page

```
package com.ninja.pages;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;

public class LoginPage
{
   //  http://tutorialsninja.com/demo/index.php?route=account/login

   WebDriver driver;

   @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//input[@id='input-email']")
   WebElement email;

   @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//input[@id='input-password']")
   WebElement password;

   @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//input[@class='btn btn-primary']")
   WebElement login;

   @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//div[@class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible']")
   WebElement warning;

   public LoginPage(
         WebDriver driver)
   {
      this.driver = driver;
   }

   public String getTitle()
   {
      return driver.getTitle();
   }

   public String doLoginValid(String email1, String pwd)
   {
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      email.sendKeys(email1);
      password.sendKeys(pwd);

      login.click();
      return driver.getTitle();
   }

   public String doLoginInValid(String email1, String pwd)
   {
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      email.sendKeys(email1);
      password.sendKeys(pwd);

      login.click();
      return warning.getText();
   }
}
```

LoginPageTest

```
package com.ninja.testcases;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import com.ninja.pages.LoginPage;
import com.ninja.util.BrowserFactory;

public class LoginPageTest
{
   static LoginPage loginPage;
   static WebDriver driver;

   @BeforeAll
   public static void makeConnection()
   {
      driver = BrowserFactory.stratBrowser("chrome");
      loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);

   }

   @BeforeEach
   public void startWebsite()
   {
      BrowserFactory.startWebsite("http://tutorialsninja.com/demo/index.php?route=account/login");
      assertEquals("Account Login", loginPage.getTitle());
   }

   @Test
   public void testDoLoginValid01()
   {
      assertEquals("My Account", loginPage.doLoginValid("ram@gmail.com", "Ram@123"));
   }

   @Test
   public void testDoLoginInvalid02()
   {
      assertEquals("Warning: No match for E-Mail Address and/or Password.",
            loginPage.doLoginInValid("ramq@gmail.com", "Ram@123"));
   }

   @Test
   public void testDoLoginInvalid03()
   {
      assertEquals("Warning: No match for E-Mail Address and/or Password.",
            loginPage.doLoginInValid("ram@gmail.com", "Rama@123"));
   }
}
```

Comment: Best practice is to have each test be independent. Part of that means each test should launch the browser, complete the test, and close the browser.

Comment: Independecy of all tests is optional, required maybe by bussines but definitely not by programming. You can loop it in a single method or choose some different approach. After confirming login credentials you can check success by many ways (app-specific webelement, url, part of url, cookie(s), cookie attribute(s), ...). So determining if user is logged in is pretty easy, all you need is to trigger next move only if user is really logged in. Include loggout after successful login before moving to next test.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes closing the browser doesn't end the session. You should have an AfterEach that tries to find and click a LogOut button